# How to allow PDF file uploads on iOS?

Tags: html, ios, forms, mobile, file-upload

### The Problem

I've built an HTML web form for the purpose of uploading files. When accessed from an iOS device, non-image files (.pdf, .docx, etc.) appear **greyed-out** when the "Browse" button is chosen to select a file from the iOS file explorer.

I have a fully-featured page (HTML, CSS, JS, PHP), but I've stripped the whole page down to the simplest form element to test functionality. Here's an example of code that **does not** work on my server (this is all that's in the HTML file besides the boilerplate tags), when viewed on a device running iOS 12.3:

```html
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <input type="file" accept="image/*, .heic, .hevc, .heif, .pdf, .png, .gif, .jpg, .jpeg, .doc, .docx, image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/gif, application/msword, application/pdf" multiple>
</form>
```

You can see a similarly simple **working** example of non-image files being selectable from an iOS device with one of the W3School's "Try It" editors:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_file

### What I've Tried

- SSL (extended validation)
- Apple technical support (referred to Apple Developer website after a couple hours on the phone)
- Multiple browsers (iOS Safari, iOS Chrome, iOS Google App)
- Multiple Apple devices (works on Mac, fails on iPhone and iPad)
- Competitive platforms (works on Android)
- **iOS 13 beta (works)**

### The Question

Something is causing W3School's and other sites' servers to behave differently than mine when working with forms on iOS.

**What is the factor on iOS that determines which sites/forms are able to select non-image files for an upload?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must remove `image/*` and the other `image/` file types.

```html
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <input type="file" accept=".heic, .hevc, .heif, .pdf, .png, .gif, .jpg, .jpeg, .doc, .docx, application/msword, application/pdf" multiple>
</form>
```

Here is a sample of your code with my corrections:
https://codepen.io/VladimirButakov/pen/XvXxGq?&editable=true

Comment: I'll test this out and let you know what I find. Any browser logic or anything behind why the "image/" filetypes would affect non-image uploads?

Comment: In my testing, this works! I'd still love to know the logic behind it, as I've been unable to find documentation. Your experience has been a true life-saver today.

Answer (score 1):

I made a web page that can get pdf files and send them to chats over a telegram bot.
I opened the web page from my Iphone and just selected a pdf and sended it and it worked just fine.

The code I used for the input file is the following.

```
<form action="inviapdf.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="inputfile">
<input accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" class="bott" type="file" name="pdf"/>
<button>SendPDF</button>
</form>
```

I have an Iphone 7+ with latest IOS release.
If I didn't answer your question can you be a bit more specific about it? 
thanks

Comment: So, I checked the W3School example that you put there and as I was sayig it works for me.. Also I tested it with my friend phone (Iphone X with latest IOS) and it works just fine.
Instead of talking via comments contact me on telegram @AScotto133
I can show you my web page so that you'll check if it works for you.

Comment: Also I edited my answer to change some code for the "accept" part

Comment: I'd really like to award this to you, but the central question is still unanswered, and that's ``What is the "X" factor on iOS that determines which sites are able to select non-image files on a web form upload?`` I have given you an upvote because you helped me establish that it is working on some sites (including, I'm sure, yours). Now I'm just focused on figuring out why the site I've built on the server I'm using is *not* functioning like the working sites.